# How to develop Flutter web app on Windows Subsystems for Linux (Debian 10)

Tags: google-chrome, flutter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to develop Flutter web app on Windows Subsystems for Linux (Debian 10). I followed this instruction. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

First, I input these commands in my terminal and all of them worked fine.

Second, I tried `flutter doctor` command and this is the result.

```
Downloading android-arm-release/linux-x64 tools...                  2.1s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/linux-x64 tools...                1.8s
Downloading android-arm64-release/linux-x64 tools...                1.6s
Downloading android-x64-profile/linux-x64 tools...                  1.6s
Downloading android-x64-release/linux-x64 tools...                  1.5s
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.18.0-11.1.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I develop web app, so I don't need `Android toolchain` and `Android Studio`, but I need `Chrome`.

I think there are two ways.

1. install Chrome on WSL => I searched the Internet, but I couldn't find the way to do so.
2. user Chrome on Windows 10(not WSL) => I searched the Internet (for example:`flutter chrome "windows subsystems for linux"`), but I couldn't find the way to do so.

Could you give me any advice?

Comment: Why do you want to use WSL? Why not just use Android Studio or Visual Studio code for developing a Flutter Web App?

Comment: @mFeinstein Thank you for your comment. I have a Windows PC, but I like Linux. So I use WSL. As a code editor I use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio Code so why not just run everything there? VS Code will hot reload and hot restart automatically for you, in Linux you will have to type commands for this.

Comment: @mFeinstein So, you install Flutter SDK on Windows, right? I develop my web apps on WSL. Therefore it is difficult for me to use Windows only for Flutter.

Comment: Why then you use WSL and not just a Debian machine, no Windows at all?

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` to the path of the Chrome executable installed on Windows.

Comment: @mFeinstein I use Windows because I have to use Microsoft Office and Creative Cloud. I set ```CHROME_EXECUTABLE``` and everything worked perfectly. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Ok, so I will add this as the Answer so it can be documented for the future and you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable CHROME_EXECUTABLE to the path of the Chrome executable installed on Windows, so Flutter can locate it.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to use GUI Apps, which requires WSL version 2 and Windows 11. [Read More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps)

##### Making WSL and GUI Apps ready

**If you don't already have wsl**, run Powershell in Admin mode and run

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
sudo apt update
```

*change the distro as you like*

**If you have**, run these to make sure it's ready

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --update
wsl --shutdown
sudo apt update
```

##### Installing Google Chrome on WSL

1. Change directories into the temp folder: `cd /tmp`
2. Use wget to download it: `sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
3. Get the current stable version: `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
4. Fix the package: `sudo apt install --fix-broken -y`
5. Configure the package: `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

To launch, enter: `google-chrome`

##### You should be good to go

Running `flutter doctor` should mark web development as ready, and projects should run with this command:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: Set the chrome executable path on Windows host as shown in the figure]

Turns out, you just need to tell flutter where chrome.exe is located on your host windows machine!

Comment: for Brave & Windows users enter in the variable value: C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe

Comment: Do you have to forward ports or something else? After setting this, I receive the following
`flutter run -d chrome

  Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FormatException: Invalid UTF-8
byte (at offset 41)".`

Answer (score 0):

My WSL2(Windows 10 build 18363) did not recognise the environment variable CHROME_EXECUTABLE.

So, I also added the environment variable WSLENV to 'CHROME_EXECUTABLE/p'.
(https://adamtheautomator.com/windows-subsystem-for-linux/#Sharing_Environment_Variables)

Then, it works!